# Database design for PHP website to track price change over time

Tags: mysql, database

I want to make a website that tracks the price of objects in an online game over time. It's important to save the price not just at the moment but historically over the last few weeks in order to show a degree of change (+5% or -3% etc)

There are about 800 objects I want to track and their price gets updated every hour.

First, how would I structure that database? A ObjectPRICE table for each object?

Second, simple maths tells me to track all prices over the last three weeks would be about 400000 pieces of data? Is this prohibitively large for my relatively meager hosting means? How many prices should I save to work out the "trend"?

Comment: If you are limited on space - with every 1000 records per item (for example) you could save a summary record and delete the detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you just an ObjectPrice table with three columns: 1) a "many to one" non-unique link to object's primary id, 2) price, 3) timestamp.  From there you could schedule a cron job to query that data to get your average changes over a week's time and write those to a weekly summary table, and then delete the raw ObjectPrice rows that you just summarized, all defined by the timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

```
Table object:
objID       Auto Increment Integer 
Name        varChar 255 (or whatever size you need)

Table objectPrice:
objID       Integer
price       Decimal (19,4)
dateEntered Timestamp
```

If you are limited on space - with every 1000 records per item (for example) you could save a summary record and delete the detail - perhaps in an `objSummary` table. Without knowing all the data you need saved, you will want to add fields as needed (e.g. percentChange)

```
Table objectSummary:
objID       Integer
avePrice    Decimal (19,4)
dateEntered Timestamp
```

Answer (score 0):

Your idea with two tables is perfectly valid:

```
Object(id, objectPriceId)
ObjectPrice(id, objectId, price, date)
```

I recommend to add a reference to the actual price (`objectPriceId`). This makes it efficient to find the current price of an object.

> 400000 pieces of data? Is this prohibitively large for my relatively meager hosting means?

On something like a mobile phone this might become large, but not in a web hosting environment.